# Global fit with constraints on parameters with regards to variables in lmfit

Tags: python, lmfit

I've seen this asked a couple of times before. But for this example, I'm failing to implement techniques explained: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61182584/constraint-on-parameters-in-lmfit)
and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236362/different-constraints-for-fit-parameter-in-lmfit-model). Whether that's my own fault or that this fitting is different, I don't know. Here goes.

A simple version of the function I'm trying to fit is `y = (1-(x/chi)**beta)**(1/beta)`(1) where `chi = xi*(k**alpha)`. Where `x`  and `y` are variable and `chi, k, xi, beta, alpha` are parameters.

Now (1) of course gives NaN values when `x / chi > 1`. My questions are: **how can I implement this kind of constraint on chi being larger than x for every x?** 
In the data, values for x are strictly increasing, say `[0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5]`. One idea I've come up with is assigning a parameter `x_max` to the largest value of `x` for every fit. But I'm failing to connect that parameter to `alpha`. My code is:

```
def model(x, k, alpha, beta, xi):
     chi = xi*(k**alpha)
     y = (1 - (x/chi_fit)**beta)**(1/beta)
     return y

params = Parameters()
params.add('k', value=5, vary=False)
params.add('beta', value=1.16, min=1.1, max=1.2)
params.add('xi', value=1.3, min = 1.1, max=1.5)
params.add('x_max', value = max(x[i]), max=10, vary=True)
params.add('alpha', expr = '')
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: wait, what? You eq (1) is not NaN when x/chi > 1.   But: you cannot implement a constraint that is different for each `x`.  What you might be able to do is detect and get rid of `NaN` values.    Also: it is pointless to try to vary all of `k`, `xi`, and `alpha` if you are only using them together as `chi=xi*(k**alpha)`.  Just have `chi` be your parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  My mistake, sorry about that. The correct model is `y = (1 - (x/chi_fit)**beta)**(1/beta)` which I have edited in. The parameters are part of theory so I'd always need the values for all of them. Is it a valid idea to fit only using `chi` to find the approx. value for it and then fit again with the rest of the parameters, binding them to each other and `chi`? Say, the first fit giving `chi = 1.2`, then fitting again with some expression that tells the fit that `xi = 1.2/(k**alpha)` and so forth. Or is that nonsense?

Comment: chi=10 if xi, k, alpha=(10,1,1) or (1,10, 1), or (1,100, 0.5) or an infinite set of points in between.  The way you've formulated the problem,  the result does not depend on the relative value of xi and k, only on chi (which maybe you also called chi_fit).

Comment: absolutely agree with @MNewville, the only thing that makes sense is fitting `chi`. You need other data and according relationships to get information on `alpha` etc.